# Facebook share link with metadatas from android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

I implement sharing on facebook in my android app and according to facebook share sdk for android there is no option to share a link that will look like this :

[image]

As I dived into the docs - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/
I see that there is only option to add these metadatas that will eventually show the link as the above only from facebook javascript sdk ? how can I make the link that I share from the android app also appear like that ?
If my app uses firebase and cloud functions with Node.js, can I somehow make a function that will work it out ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, you can not add this meta data dynamically via the JS SDK any more either. The possibility to overwrite the OG meta information at the time of sharing has been completely removed (with the single exception of making posts on pages via API, then it works for domains the page has previously claimed ownership for), because it caused too much trouble (people posting an article from a renowned source, but “faking” the title/description/thumbnail while doing so, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to add a custom title, description or image for the links you share to Facebook and other popular social media services. When you share a link in the text area of the Facebook post or a Twitter tweet, they check for the meta tags in the link.

For `example`, if you visit `https://stackoverflow.com`, you can check the meta tags associated with the site by inspecting the page using your browser.

```
<meta property="og:type" content= "website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Stack Overflow" />
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" />

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="name" content="Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers" />
<meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Stack Overflow | The World&#x2019;s Largest Online Community for Developers" />
```

If you see above, there are two sections in the HTML with meta tags starting with `og:` and `twitter:`. These are meta tags instructing the mediums to use the data available here for displaying the title, description and image - i.e. on the Facebook post in your case.

Learn more about the `Open Graph Protocol (og)` [here](https://ogp.me).